# Big Integer multiplication(recursion) in java stops without an error for input of size of the order of 2000 digits. Why?

Tags: java, recursion, biginteger

I've written a recursive program in java to multiply *TWO* large integers. I get the input  as a string and store it in an int array which holds each digit in its each cell and my entire program works on the two int arrays. My program works fine for inputs of size around 1000 digits. When i give input of around 2000 digits my program simply stops( in eclipse). No "Not responding" status , no error/notification messages and NO OUTPUT. I want to know what is the catch that bounds the working-limit size for my program input. Is it because I use recursion and there isn't enough memory for storing the stack frames?

Here is the core of my program

```
private int[] bigInt(int[] a, int[] b, int expo) {
    if(n1==1)
    {
        result=multiply(a[a.length-1],b[a.length-1]);
        if(expo!=0)
            result=exponential(result,expo);
    }
    else
    {
        int A1[]=divideArray(a,0,n1/2);
        int A2[]=divideArray(a,n1/2,n1);
        int B1[]=divideArray(b,0,n2/2);
        int B2[]=divideArray(b,n2/2,n2);
        int tempA[]=bigInt(A1,B1,0);
        int A[]=exponential(tempA, n1);

        int[] addB=addArray(B1,B2);
        int[] addA=addArray(A1,A2);
        int Byet[]=bigInt(addA,addB,0);
        int C[]=bigInt(A2,B2,0);
        int B[]=subArray(Byet,tempA,C,n1/2);

        result=addArray(A,addArray(B,C));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How many time does this function get called? Do wait a little to see actually it is working?

Comment: Looks like twice for each subdivision of the array.  I can't tell you how many more times it's called since `n1` just comes out of nowhere.

Comment: have you considered using [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) ?

Comment: did you try to run it in the debugger and pause it and look at the stack trace ?

Comment: " my program simply stops( in eclipse). No "Not responding" status , no error/notification messages and NO OUTPUT" -- This is indicative of an infinite loop.  Any loops in any of the functions not shown?  How's your CPU load when this happens?

Comment: Thanks for that. I see the result for my input (no matter how large) in the debugger. But since the number of digits exceeds the range of int, I can't get it to be printed. It's pretty sad that the result is there but still can't use it!

Answer (score 0):

I get the output, but since it's very large it can't be printed in the console. If i print it in a file, i could see the output :)

Comment: But still, If my result is above 24,000 digits the result gets segmented and only the first portion(about 24,000 chars) of it gets written in the file. Although there are more digits in the result array which i could see in the debugger. Why???? And how is it possible to get my program print the entire result?